# Saving Modal Bootstrap details without form to sql

Tags: php, sql, database, visual-studio-code, modal-dialog

I would like to ask,

I have cards for list of activities that will be conducted. For example :

First card is for The Explorace

Second card is for International Day.

So, if the user want to register to the activity, they can click on the card button.

Then, there is a MODAL that shows details of the activity and display button to confirm the registration. If they Click Register button on the MODAL, they will be registered on that activity.

The thing is, I'm not using form in the modal. I just take the details of that activity on the database that I manually inserted. Based on most of the MODAL example, they use form on it.

I would like to save the registered activity on the database. But I dont have any idea to do it. Since the data of the MODAL is from the database itself. I would like to have another table called REGISTERED which is for the registered activity. Please help me :(

Comment: Do the user have to log into the site before they can make any selections?

Comment: yess , they need to log in first. I tried to use $_SESSION. It works for taking the email from the log in page. but i dont get the idea how to pull the program name instead.